# SQL assign value for join purpose to null field without update

Tags: sql, teradata

With this sample data...

```
c1  c2  c3
10  a   10a
11  a   **NULL**
12  a   **NULL**
13  b   13b
13  b   **NULL**
etc..
```

I want to assign `c3` value to rows where it is **`NULL`** and `c2` value is the same, but do not wish to actually update that value in table, only use it to join to another table while select runs.

I am able to do it using inner select and join, but I want to save as much processing power as possible because amount of data is huge and thought that some use of **`ISNULL`** or **`COALESCE`** should be able to do it, but I don't have enough experience to figure it on my own yet, or even say if it is possible. What do you think?

Comment: Can you show us expected result?

Comment: You need to show your current query if you want us to optimize that query (which it sounds like is the request)...

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Could there be multiple rows with the same `c2` and different (non-`NULL`) `c3`s? If so, what rule should be used to select one?

Comment: expected result: I want to join to another table t2 on t1.c3=t2.c3

Comment: Damien: no, same c2 value means that c3 should be also same, non null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select
    a.c1,
    a.c2,
    coalesce( a.c3, b.c3) as c3
   from table1 a
      left join table1 b
       on a.c2 = b.c2
             an  a.c3 is null
             and b.c3 is not null
```

this will work with the data that you have however if there is more than one row that is not null for c3 for a given c2 it will cause problems

If your DB supports `max() over` you can also do this

```
SELECT c1,
       c2,
       coalesce(c3, MAX(C3) over (partition by c2)) c3
from table1
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d78c5/3)

Comment: This is exactly my solution as c3 value is only ONE or NULL for given c2 and I was trying to find out if it is actually possible to do it some other way

Comment: @joe yes there are but you'll need to let us know what db you're using

Comment: It's teradata (oracle like, minor differences)

Answer (score 0):

A sample **`pseudo code`** which i often use in my Query.

```
DECLARE @USER_ID AS VARCHAR(256)
SELECT @USER_ID = 'abc'


select *
from CC
INNER JOIN adm_co_users CR_US WITH(NOLOCK) ON ISNULL(CR_US.original_userID,'') =
        (CASE ISNULL(CC.Createdby,'')   WHEN '' THEN @USER_ID
        ELSE CC.Createdby END )
```